# Recursively iterate over all the files in a directory and its subdirectories in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want to recursively scan a directory and all its sub-directories for files with a given extension - for example, all *.jpg files. How can you do that in QML? 
And I want to show them in ListView.

Comment: What have you tried till now? What doesn't work? Best way would be to do this in C++ with QDir & QFileInfoList and provide QAbstractListModel to QML for ListView

Answer (score 1):

`FolderListModel` is the only way to get file system access from QML. It provides a model you can iterate, although in order to get sub-directories you will have to "enter" them at model level.

You can use `nameFilters: ["*.jpg"]` so it only gives you jpg files and `showDirs: true` to gets subdirs listed in the model.

Finally, you can populate a plain qml `ListModel` with the results to show all files found in a single view.

Comment: Excuse me. Can I use "QDirIterator it(dir, QStringList() << "*.jpg", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);" to do such thing?

Comment: Not from QML. From C++ - yes.

Comment: Something to be aware of if using `FolderListModel` as a file system scan tool - it appears it's updates may be asynchronous, complicating imperative use.

Comment: `to get sub-directories you will have to "enter" them at model level.` @dtech, could you give an example of this? Specifically, it would be nice to be able to look for all `*.foo` files both in the directory `bar/` as well as in its subdirectories.